# How to open view multiple times in eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse

I want to open multiple search views  in the IDE( preferably without multiple instances of the eclipse ide). How  can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. 
But if you realy need this, register to bugzilla of eclipse and write an feature-request.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while looking for a similar answer myself;  apparently now you can, though it's not something that is achievable through menus / options etc..

take a look here http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_multiple_instances_of_the_same_view%3F